# pass secure information from one server to another

Tags: security, ssl, https

The situation is this:
A payment is made to one server, and on completion, it must notify another server securely. What I am trying to do is actually quite similar to a notify_url of a payment service. I.E. paypal receives a payment, and then notifies the origin through a long URL.

How does one verify the data being passed. Any useful libraries? Any links to get me started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) is a good way to ensure that the URL has not been generated by an unauthorized party or tampered with in any way. [Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=925) is a simple tutorial.

If the URL (or the content it returns) contains any sensitive information, then you'll also want to make sure that the recipient server is SSL enabled.

And for a further layer of security, you could hard-code the recipient server to reject any connections that aren't from the IP address(es) of your known sender(s).